# How to merge folders with different letter cases into one?

Tags: nautilus

Nautilus doesn't merge folders with the same name if one of them has uppercase letters and the other doesn't; if one is called "Folder" and the other is called "folder" then Nautilus wouldn't merge them. I have a large amount of files that I need to merge, is there a script that would allow Nautilus to mass merge them all? If not, is there another way than manually renaming all the folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is by design. File and folder names are case-sensitive in *nix systems.

Renaming can be automated in a variety of ways.  Mass renaming utilities are available, [pyrenamer [image: Install pyrenamer]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pyrenamer), 
[nautilus-renamer [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/nautilus-renamer) ,
[rename](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/prename.1.html),
 [mmv [image: Install mmv]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mmv) , to quote a few.

To complete the answer, here is a script that does the renaming for you.
`rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *`
This should rename all files/folders to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

***NO, you can't simply merge them.***

In any Linux or Unix (including Ubuntu), filenames and folder names are case sensitive.  So two similar directories but with different case can co-exist.

You need to create a shell script to rename them ..

( I will see if I can find the time to write one. )